# Insert label and zoon in a graph made in R

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I would like help on two things in the graph below:

1 - In the points of the graph, I would like to have the corresponding property number as well.

2 - Is it possible to bring the visualization of the points even closer?

Executable code below:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)

temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
download.file("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip",temp)


unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
shp <- readOGR(temp2)
shp_subset <- shp[shp$NM_MUNICIP == "CASTRO",]

#Points
Points_properties<-structure(list(Propertie = c(1,2,3,4,5), Latitude = c(-24.781624, -24.775017, -24.769196, 
 -24.761741, -24.752019), Longitude = c(-49.937369, 
-49.950576, -49.927608, -49.92762, -49.920608)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

#Generate map

marsize <- .2
par(mar = rep(marsize,4))
z <- .4
shp_subset_cropped <- raster::crop(shp_subset,
                                   extent(c(
                                     (extent(shp_subset)@"xmin"*(1-z)+z*min(Points_properties$Longitude)),
                                     (extent(shp_subset)@"xmax"*(1-z)+z*max(Points_properties$Longitude)),
                                     (extent(shp_subset)@"ymin"*(1-z)+z*min(Points_properties$Latitude)),
                                     (extent(shp_subset)@"ymax"*(1-z)+z*max(Points_properties$Latitude))
                                   )))
plot(shp_subset_cropped)

points(x = Points_properties$Longitude,
       y= Points_properties$Latitude, col = "black",pch = 16,cex=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Example data

```
Points_properties <- data.frame(Propertie = c(1,2,3,4,5), Latitude = c(-24.781624, -24.775017, -24.769196, 
 -24.761741, -24.752019), Longitude = c(-49.937369, 
-49.950576, -49.927608, -49.92762, -49.920608))

library(terra)
v <- vect(Points_properties, c("Longitude", "Latitude"))

# simple example polygon, to avoid the need for downloads
m <- matrix(c(-49.986, -49.861, -49.866, -50.029, -24.673, -24.728, -24.832, -24.797), ncol=2)
p <- vect(m, "polygons")
```

Plot the points first. You can use the "ext" argument to expand the area mapped (or xlim and ylim); and then use `text`.

```
plot(v, ext=ext(v) + .05)
text(v, v$Propertie, pos=4)
lines(p)
```

You can also plot the labels instead of the points:

```
plot(v, ext=ext(v) + .05, cex=0)
text(v, v$Propertie)
```